# How do I find an optimal FPS for best user experience while preserving battery life?

Tags: android, mobile, frame-rate, user-experience

I'm developing an Android game. The "graphics" I'm using need little CPU/GPU, so they run with high FPS. Because saving energy is important on Android devices, I want to limit frame-rate (`if deltaTime < limitDeltaTime -> Thread.sleep(...)` ).

How high should the frame-rate be to get an optimal balance between saving resources and a "fluid" gameplay experience. At which point is the user experience optimal or no longer improving?

Answer (score 6):

The lowest framerate you can get away with depends on the game.

In chess, a **still image** is just fine until someone makes a move! In a fast-paced FPS, you'll typically want **>30** frames per second.

[This comparison](http://boallen.com/fps-compare.html) of an animation at 15, 30 and 60 frames/second should give you a rough idea, but it's best just to try it out -- every game is different.

Comment: I'll second that it depends a lot on the game, so it's best to try it out. There's a common misconception that XX FPS is enough and above which people can't notice; in truth it depends on the type of motion, the contrast of the scene, whether effects like motion blur are used and so on.

Comment: Wow, that hurt my eyes XD.